# Using Google Analytics when switching subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

We have a subdomain (e.g. subdomain.mydomain.com) and have Google Analytics tracking for that specific subdomain.

We are rebranding the service and will be changing the subdomain (e.g. newsubdomain.mydomain.com)

I'd like to use the same tracking code so all my stats are in the same property moving forward.  What settings do I need to change in Google Analytics?  I see one setting for Default URL.  Just wondering if there are any others that need to be updated.

If it matters, we are also using Google Tag Manager to track outbound link clicks.  I see several references in there to the old domain so I'll update those when we switch over.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have to do anything. Since you're still on the same domain, the cookies will be consistent across. You can keep everything the same, I don't even think the "default url" was necessary to change.

Comment: I created a sample page on the new subdomain and visited it a few times yesterday.  It hasn't registered those pageviews so something is not working right.  I'm wondering if the Default URL being set to subdomain.mydomain.com instead of newsubdomian.mydomain.com is making a difference.

Comment: Also, we are a large organization and I don't control the TLD.  So all this analytics tracking is for subdomains, if that makes a difference.